# How to set the first child as Add button in Android Gridview?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, grid

I want to make a first child item of grid view as "Add" button like below the image Link. Data should be appear on from position 1, not a position 0. Don't suggest the headerview, I tried it. please give me some great ideas to do that.

[Click here to view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llnO5.jpg)

Comment: use if else in getView. Like  If(positon == 0){//then add} else{//data}.

Comment: Why there ? you can use floating button with full grid view. now a days it is best way to perform some action

Comment: Just add a item at index 0 in your adapter's data set . As after seeing image clearly this is Grid's first item So there is no other way to do it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your adapter's `getView` method, do this check:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    // ...
    // ...
    if (position == 0) {
       yourImageView.setImageResource(mContext.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.your_add_img));
    }
    return convertView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be quite easy. If you have an adapter, just check if you're in the first indexing position and then add the button. If you're not you add your images.